# How can I prove the convergence of the following series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series are the following:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n  \sin \left(\frac{1+n^2}{n^3}\right)   $$

Is there a way to prove it by the Squeeze theorem?

Comment: What makes you think it converges? For $n$ large, the term is approximately $\frac{n+n^3}{n^3}>1$.

Comment: Well... I noticed this too, that while n grows to infinity the sine will become zero. If I apply the limit test, I get inf times zero. How can I prove it in a mathematical way?

Comment: So what? As $n\to\infty$ , it is also true that $\frac{1+n^2}{n^3}\to 0$, but that doesn't mean $n\frac{1+n^2}{n^3}\to 0$.

Comment: This is $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin(x)/x$ in disguise.

Comment: So... May I need to use another test? Which one do you recommend me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+n^2}{n^3}=0$, so

$$\begin{align*}
1&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1+n^2}{n^3}\right)}{\frac{1+n^2}{n^3}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n\sin\left(\frac{1+n^2}{n^3}\right)\cdot\frac{n^2}{1+n^2}\right)\\
&=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin\left(\frac{1+n^2}{n^3}\right)\right)\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{1+n^2}\right)\;.
\end{align*}$$

What does this tell you about

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin\left(\frac{1+n^2}{n^3}\right)\;?$$

And what does that tell you about the series?

Comment: As the limit is equal to 1, the limit test says that the series diverge?

Comment: @Joshua: That’s right.

Comment: @Joshua: It’s one of the standard limits: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$.

Comment: Oh... I didn't see it. Thanks!

Comment: @Joshua: You’re welcome!